# Регулярное выражение возвращает два значения вместо одного

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Парсинг значений по сайту. Есть  код страницы (фрагмент из r.text4)

```
 }]},{ id :8428, name : CLTC纯电续航里程(km) , pnid : 1_-1 , valueitems :[{ specid 
 :59748, value : 550 },{ specid :59749, value : 535 },{ specid :52972, value : 550 },{ 
 specid :53240, value : 535 }]},{ id :1292, name : <span class= hs_kw36_configlt >< 
 span><span class= hs_kw37_configlt >< span>(小时) , pnid : 1_-1 , valueitems :[{ specid 
 :59748, value : 0.75 },{ specid :59749, value : 0.75 },{ specid :52972, value : 0.75 }, 
 { specid :53240, value : 0.75 }]},{ id :8454, name :
```

он обрабатывается выражением:

```
 NEDCa=r"id :8428, name.{50,100}?value : (\d\d\d)"
 NEDC=str(re.findall (NEDCa, r.text4))
```

вместо ожидаемого получения числа `550` за одну итерацию выдает пару значений:

```
['550', '550']
```

алгоритм в цикле собирает все 4 значения, все работает норм, везде  пары берет

Comment: А значения id :8428 не появляются на сайте еще раз?

Comment: Я чет туплю и не понимаю, вы про группы в регулярных выражениях не слышали?

Comment: @ipatev_nn не, у него под шаблон регулярки только 550 попадает в группу :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков само регулярное выражение верно и процесс работает правильно, но у автора вопроса происходит задвоение результат, поэтому проблема тут не в группе, а в данных.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvdtb.png

Comment: данные достаточно типичны, это дамп большой таблицы, и в остальных случаях с подобным синтаксисом все отрабатывает нормально. Ну ладно. будем искать обходы, split remove. что ли...
Значение с таким айди еще раз появляется, но после него идет link а не name. Для того нейм и оставлен в запросе.

Comment: Что бы понять причину возникновения проблемы, нужен минимальный воспроизводимый пример, в текущем виде проблема не воспроизводится, все отрабатывает согласно логики

Answer (score 0):

Решить базовый вопрос не удалось. Был применен метод дополнительной обработки некачественной выборки. Костыль. Из результата (парные значения, получающиеся в ходе поиска регулярным выражением, при том что известна маска ответа, делается выборка с помощью индекса переменной.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).